# In an R dataframe, identify/remove rows with at least two duplicate values

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, rows

Suppose we have an R dataframe. How can we identify (and remove) any rows where some value occurs at least two times? After some searching, I still can not find a solution on the web. A small code example illustrates what I am after:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(10, 20, 30, 50), y = c(30, 40, 40, 50), 
                   z = c(40, 50, 10, 50), w = c(50, 40, 50, 50))
```

This gives the dataframe

```
>df
   x  y  z  w
1 10 30 40 50
2 20 40 50 40
3 30 40 10 50
4 50 50 50 50
```

So, df has duplicate values in row 2 and 4, and I want to remove those rows, to get the `result`:

```
> result
   x  y  z  w
1 10 30 40 50
3 30 40 10 50
```

For my application I can use a solution where one assumes there are just four columns, although of course a general solution would be better.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option in `base R` - loop over the rows with `apply`, check for duplicates (`anyDuplicated` - return the index of first duplicate, if no duplicates, it returns 0), then negate (`!` - so that 0 becomes TRUE and all others FALSE) to subset the rows

```
df[!apply(df, 1, anyDuplicated),]
```

-output

```
  x  y  z  w
1 10 30 40 50
3 30 40 10 50
```